# How to add UIButton in front on UIWebView objective C

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uibutton

I want to show a UIButton on a UIWebview.
However the UIButton shows behind the webview.

i have tried the below code:

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {
        if(navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && [[request.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString:myURL])
        {

            [_myBtn bringSubviewToFront:self.view];

            [self.myWebView addSubview:_myBtn];

 //i have tried this aswell

            //[_myBtn bringSubviewToFront:self.myWebView];

            //[self.view addSubview:_myBtn];

            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Any Ideas, what i am doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: are you adding button in Storyboard? then just move button below the `WebView`

Comment: yes sir, i am adding it in storyboard

Comment: just move button below the WebView

Comment: yes that i know and i have done that already, still it shows behind the webview

Comment: Still button is not visible on WebView? Comment out above code and check

Comment: Button is visible through the webview(its opacity is .8)
so i can see the button behind the webview.

Comment: OMG thanks a lot, i have been trying that for like 2 hours, thanks a lot

Comment: have you found issue?

Comment: yes sir, thanks a lot, i think you should provide the answer so that can be accepted.
it may help some one else.

Comment: yup.. Cool Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out above code and Just move `UIButton` below the `UIWebView` in your Storyboard and then check.